# Intersection of functions and the ratio of curvature and slope

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have two functions $f: \mathbb{R_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, both strictly increasing, strictly concave, and twice differentiable. For all $x \in [a,b]$, $b>a \geq 0$, it holds that $f''/f' > g''/g'$. My question is: Is it possible for $f$ and $g$ to intersect more than twice on $[a,b]$, that is, to have $f(x) = g(x)$ for three or more different $x \in [a,b]$?

I know that this is definitely not the case when both $f''/f'$ and $g''/g'$ are constant, because in that case $f$ and $g$ are limited to a class of exponential functions (i.e., $f(x) = -\exp(-a x)$ or some affine transformation) which makes it easy to show. But what if the ratio can depend on $x$?

Edit: Thanks, bubba. I got it know.

Let $h = f - g$. Then $h' = 0 \Leftrightarrow f' = g'$. Then $f''/f' > g''/g'$ implies $f'' > g''$ or $h'' > 0$. Thus, every local extremum must be a local minimum, which implies that $h(x) = 0$ for at most two different values of $x$.

Comment: Would probably be easier to state (and solve) if we set $h=f-g$ and thought about zeros of $h$.

Comment: If you're interested in gaining some rep points, post your last paragraph as an answer. I'd vote for it.